# connect to socks5 proxy in LSP

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I installed my LSP and it works well.Then I want to make a redirection to socks5 proxy in my LSP(it's mostly for TCP connection). The proxy's Ip and port are correct.

I realized I must focus on the WSPConnect function,so I hijacked it and make my own ProxyConnect function executes firstly.But I found it always failed when I call the lower provider's lpWSPConnect function to connect the proxy server.

```
g_NextProcTable.lpWSPConnect(s, (sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(sockaddr), &DataBuf, lpCalleeData, lpSQOS, lpGQOS, &err);
```

Then,I noticed that the WSPAsyncSelect function and WSPSelect function were called as well.

I think I should handle these two carefully otherwise the application cannot connect to the proxy server,because the appliction's socket may be asynchronous.But I don't know how to deal with.I would appreciate any ideas on this. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

write in lsp:

1: wspasyncSelect and eventselect, remember there params;

2: before connect: clear the event(async and eventselect);using wspioctl setting socket into blocking mode;

3: connect to your socks5 server using rfc 1928 rules

4: reset event(async and eventSelect) to socket